# SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable() , For choice fields its adding extra string ";#" in the datatable

Tags: 2013, export, splistitemcollection, datatable

```
SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(query);  
dataTable = collListItems.GetDataTable();
```

I am using above for getting listitemcollection into datatable. In the list I have choice column (checkbox) which allows multiple values. But in datatable I got additinal characters for choice field column.

> ";#Choice1;#Choice2;#"

How can I remove those extra character from datatable.

Comment: What do you want to get after removing additional characters?

Comment: I am using that datatable to export the list view in timer job and send to via email. To make excel more readable I need to remove those extra characters.

Comment: I mean the final output will be like "Choice1 Choice2"?

Comment: Either " Choice1,Choice2 " or "Choice1 ; Choice2". In readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop into the data table and remove additional characters

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
     {
        row["Your Coumn Name"] = ReplaceByRegex(row["Your Coumn Name"])      
     }
```

Just write a function what replaces additional characters using [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). Currently, I am unable to write the whole method. Try and let me know.

Comment: But Atish , I am having nearly 2500 items in the list view. It will take much time if I loop through all.

Comment: I can not think anything else rather than looping. It is the default behavior of Choice column that saves multiple items separated by ";#". Anyway, How are you using it? Meaning that when you are using this column, you can modify these additional characters at that time also by Regex.

Comment: I am simply binding datatable to DataGrid and then used streamwriter and htmltextwriter to add this DataGrid to excel.

Comment: Got that but no hope except looping!